# implementing the generic interface

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, generics, interface

Could any one help me on exposing the below class methods thru an Interface . I want to be able to use the below Cache class methods through an interface. Basically need to Create an generic interface with common cache methods defined and their implementation will be provided in below class

```
public  class CacheStore
{
    private  Dictionary<string, object> _cache;
    private  object _sync;

    public CacheStore()
    {
        _cache = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        _sync = new object();
    }

    public  bool Exists<T>(string key) where T : class
    {
        Type type = typeof(T);

        lock (_sync)
        {
            return _cache.ContainsKey(type.Name + key);
        }
    }

    public  bool Exists<T>() where T : class
    {
        Type type = typeof(T);

        lock (_sync)
        {
            return _cache.ContainsKey(type.Name);
        }
    }

    public  T Get<T>(string key) where T : class
    {
        Type type = typeof(T);

        lock (_sync)
        {
            if (_cache.ContainsKey(key + type.Name) == false)
                throw new ApplicationException(String.Format("An object with key '{0}' does not exists", key));

            lock (_sync)
            {
                return (T)_cache[key + type.Name];
            }
        }
    }

    public  void Add<T>(string key, T value)
    {
        Type type = typeof(T);

        if (value.GetType() != type)
            throw new ApplicationException(String.Format("The type of value passed to 
            cache {0} does not match the cache type {1} for key {2}",     
            value.GetType().FullName, type.FullName, key));

        lock (_sync)
        {
            if (_cache.ContainsKey(key + type.Name))
                throw new ApplicationException(String.Format("An object with key '{0}'  
                already exists", key));

            lock (_sync)
            {
                _cache.Add(key + type.Name, value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What interface? It's not clear what you are asking.

Comment: just extract method signatures into an interface, remove `public`, give interface a name and you're done

Answer (score 3):

You can easily extract an interface as follows.

```
interface ICache
{
    bool Exists<T>(string key) where T : class;
    bool Exists<T>() where T : class;
    T Get<T>(string key) where T : class;
    void Add<T>(string key, T value);
}
```

Now you can make your class implement it by doing `class CacheStore : ICache`.

---

Aside: Rather than using string concatenation of the key and type name, you could simply make your `Dictionary` key type a `Tuple<Type, string>`:

```
private Dictionary<Tuple<Type, string>, object> _cache;
```

To make it clear, here's how you could reimplement your first `Exists` method with this change:

```
public bool Exists<T>(string key) where T : class
{
    Type type = typeof(T);

    lock (_sync)
    {
        return _cache.ContainsKey(Tuple.Create(type, key));
    }
}
```

This will be a little cleaner and has the advantage of allowing you to not have to worry about name collisions. With your current setup, what if I added a `Location` with key `"FriendGeo"` and a `GeoLocation` with key `"Friend"`? They both concatenate to form the same string, `"FriendGeoLocation"`. This might seem contrived, but if it did end up happening you'd get very strange (and wrong) behavior that would be hard to debug.

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool to do this automatically in Visual Studio.  Right-click in the class, choose Refactor, Extract Interface, Select All, Ok.